# php operators && vs AND, || vs OR

Tags: php, operators

I'm just started with php. I used to use `AND` and `OR` but found out about `&&` and `||`, what is the difference of these operators?

Comment: I'm not very into php, but as I heard they have different priority level.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "||" has a greater precedence than "or"
>
> "&&" has a greater precedence than "and"

From php manual, can read the full article [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (Exemple1)